# Cannot set map options with vue2-leaflet-googlemutant

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, leaflet

I want to `vue2-leaflet-googlemutant` and want to disable & enable some Google Maps' buttons (e.g., `streetViewControl`, `traffic`, etc.)

I tried with the following code:

```html
<LMap style="display: block;" :zoom="14" :center="initialLocation" :option="{ Vue2Leaflet: true }" ref="myMap">
      <Vue2LeafletGoogleMutant :apikey="apikey" :options="{
        type: 'satellite',
        streetViewControl: true,
      }"></Vue2LeafletGoogleMutant>
</LMap>
```

Only type: '**satellite**', works and the map is shown in sattelite mode. However, the streetViewControl option doesn't work.

What do I have to do to be able to add map options like `zoomControl`, etc.?

Comment: From GoogleMutant's readme.md - "GoogleMutant is meant to provide a reliable (and ToC-compliant) way of loading Google Map's tiles into Leaflet, nothing more." - if you want to add controls etc to the map, they need to be Leaflet controls. The plugin won't transpose a Google Maps control into a Leaflet control for you.